# Orientation with multiple view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

Is it possible to have the following?

When I rotate my iOS Device, the ViewController switches, as in I have RandomViewControllerPortrait and RandomViewControllerLandscape. I have the feeling that if I support both orientations, that the ViewController class gets quite "bloated".

Is this idea useful at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having 2 view controllers for different rotations would be a bit redundant. I think what you want to use is 2 different UIViews for different orientations, and your UIViewController handling the methods for rotations being called. When your application rotates, you can set self.view to be either portraitView or landscapeView. You can even animate the view change with an animation block, so the transition looks smoother.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Of course this sounds more elegant - Weird that I didn't came up with that :)